# Debugging an existing sharepoint solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, iis, sharepoint-2010, build

I've recently mapped a sharepoint solution from TFS to a local directory and successfully 'got' the latest version.

It wasn't building, but this was because of there were no Site URL's in the properties of the several projects included in the solution. So, using central admin, I created a new web app (the port 36352). U then added the url and port to the Site Url and it's now building fine.

However, when I go to run with the debugger I get the following two errors:

---

Error 2 Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': Cannot connect to the SharePoint site: **:36352/">http://**:36352/ (deleted url for security reasons). Make sure that this is a valid URL and the SharePoint site is running on the local computer. If you moved this project to a new computer or if the URL of the SharePoint site has changed since you created the project, update the Site URL property of the project.

AND

Error 3 Program 'Path.PowerShell.exe' (deleted path for security reasons) does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

---

It seems that the first error is related to the way in which I've 'connected' it to the new web app I've created - have I done this part right?

The 2nd error seems to be with regard to the entry point at which the debugger should execute, but this is a sharepoint site - so I just want to run the site (has VS not identified this as sharepoint somehow?).

Thanks a LOT for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this exception when I had the solution on a different server. Make sure your solution is on the same server as the SharePoint web application. When you run the solution, Visual studio packages the solution and tries to deploy it onto the URL you specified in the properties. If your project is a farm solutions such as visual web part then make sure you have rights to deploy.